# Is that a chrome bug or react's? or something I am not understanding or doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, console.log

I have an object courseSectionsObject in state with just 5 entries and all as false first. Then I copy that into an object and console log it before and after mutating it. It shows result as it is but after expanding that result object on chrome console, it shows different value than it is showing before expanding. WHY IS THAT? The values it is showing after expanding is the final result that I am doing console log after it.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hover over that little `i`, you'll see a tooltip saying `Object below was evaluated just now`.  Meaning that the object is only evaluated when you toggle that object open.  That's a feature of Chrome.

Open up your dev console in Chrome, run the below snippet, and open those objects.  Obviously the first one should be `a: true` but when evaluated on the fly, it shows `a: false`.

```js
const obj = { a: true };
console.log(obj);
obj.a = false;
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Oh, it works just like you said. But I couldn't understand how this feature of chrome is helpful?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's helpful perse, but probably for conserving resources, since half of the stuff logged never gets opened.  Just a guess though.